# How to show what programs are running from the panel on the desktop?

Tags: 12.04

In 12.04, I wonder how to show what programs are running from the panel on the desktop? In 10.10, I managed to create a drop list of opened applications, which takes little space when it is folded up. But in 12.04, I have no idea how because I forget how I did it in 10.10. Thanks!

Comment: I forget how I did it in 10.10. Probably some options when editing the property of the panel. I can't find I can edit panel properties in 12.04.

Comment: 10.10 used Gnome2, with a different panel, so you may have added a gnome panel applet.  You could try installing and making a shortcut to "htop" or using the standard "top", and adding the shortcut to the launcher.

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your question as saying 11.10 (11.10 is much more similar to 12.04 LTS than is 10.10).

Comment: Although @Tim has signed on recently this question appears to be abandoned. Additionally it surrounds 10.10, 11.10 and 12.04 which are all EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.